# Branching points of a multi-valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, branch-points

Consider $g(z) =  w $, where $w^3 - 3w -z = 0  $( $g$ is the inverse of $f(z) = z^3 - 3z$). What are the branching points of $g(z)$? Sketch the scheme of the Riemann surface of $g(z)$

I know that the idea behind branching points is to make a multi-valued function behave like a single-valued function in some regions. But, how do I determine what ought to be the branching points in this case? Is there any procedure for such functions? I have also no clue about how to work out the scheme of the Riemann surface for $g(z)$.

Comment: If $f'(a)\ne 0$ then the branch of $f^{-1}$ such that $f^{-1}(f(a))=a$ is analytic around $f(a)$.

Comment: @reuns I have fixed the error.

Comment: Yes. So where is $f^{-1}$ non analytic?